# Why are my TikZ intersections not exact?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

In a TikZ picture, I try to intersect an arc with a cubic bezier line. However, the calculated intersection points seem off — do you know why that is? Is this some sort of rounding error?

[image: zoom on the intersection]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    detector/.style={line width=0.5pt, color=gray, line cap=round},
    track/.style={line width=0.9pt, color=black, -{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    seed track/.style={track, color=blue},
    red dot/.style={red, opacity=0.3}
]

\draw[detector, name path=L1] (0,20mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=20mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L2] (0,30mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=30mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L3] (0,50mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=50mm];

\draw[seed track, name path=curler track, opacity=0.6] (0,0) .. controls (0,0) and (52mm, 8mm) .. (21mm, 62mm);

\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L3 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L2 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L1 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because adding a "quick" arrow distorts the path. Fixing the problem is as simple as loading the `bending` library, see p. 204 of the pgfmanual version 3.1.8b:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    detector/.style={line width=0.5pt, color=gray, line cap=round},
    track/.style={line width=0.9pt, color=black, -{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    seed track/.style={track, color=blue},
    red dot/.style={red, opacity=0.3}
]

\draw[detector, name path=L1] (0,20mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=20mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L2] (0,30mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=30mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L3] (0,50mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=50mm];

\draw[seed track, name path=curler track, opacity=0.6] (0,0) .. controls (0,0) and (52mm, 8mm) .. (21mm, 62mm);

\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L3 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L2 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L1 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have an explicit comparison, let us quickly add a `quick` arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    detector/.style={line width=0.5pt, color=gray, line cap=round},
    track/.style={line width=0.9pt, color=black, -{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    seed track/.style={track, color=blue},
    red dot/.style={red, opacity=0.3}
]

\draw[detector, name path=L1] (0,20mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=20mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L2] (0,30mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=30mm];
\draw[detector, name path=L3] (0,50mm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=50mm];

\draw[seed track, name path=curler track, opacity=0.6] (0,0) .. controls (0,0) and (52mm, 8mm) .. (21mm, 62mm);
\draw[dashed,red,-{Latex[length=2mm,quick]}] (0,0) .. controls (0,0) and (52mm, 8mm) .. (21mm, 62mm);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L3 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L2 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
\fill[red dot, name intersections={of=L1 and curler track}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the "quick" curve is off, and matches the one you had in your example.

Needless to say that you could also bend the arrow if you load `bending`, but this is not central to the current question.

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you very much! That was indeed a very easy fix :) — and welcome to TeX.SE!